# Many to Many to One relationship

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent

I've got four tables `Users[user_id] - role_user[user_id,role_id] - Roles[role_id] - Permissions[role_id]`. A User could have many Roles, while the Role has many Permissions. So, a Permission has one Role, while a Role belongs to many Users.

```
// User.php ...
class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }
}

// Roles.php
class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Permission');
    }

}

// Permission.php

class Permission extends Model
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Role');
    }
}
```

I guess the real question is; can you chain relationship methods, like: App\User::find(1)->roles->permissions;  I don't think you can because the `->roles` returns a `Collection` and not an eloquent model, so the permissions method doesn't exists off `roles`.

Is there another way I can get the collection of permissions for all roles for a given use, preferably with a single line?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I haven't tested it, but I think this will work or work with very small twick. Add this function in your User Model.</strike>

```
public function getPermission($id){

        $roles = Roles::where('user_id','=', id)->get();

        $permissions = array();

        foreach($roles as $role){

            array_push($permissions, $role->permissions);

        }

        return $permissions;

    }
```

and access as `$user->getPermission($user->id);`. This might not be the best solution, but it should solve the problem.

**UPDATED CODE**
    You can use accessor like the example bellow and this will return a permission collection. Use this function in your User Model

```
public function getPermissions($value){

        $role_ids = Roles::where('user_id','=', $value)
            ->select(array('permission_id'))
            ->toArray();

        return Permission::find($role_ids);

    }
```

and access it like `$permissions = App\User::find(1)->permissions;`. I believe this will work as you expected.